# in_array function not working when using variable?

Tags: php, wordpress

In my below code I am trying to check whether the `$query['skill']` value is contained in `$c_skills`. However it keeps failing. When I use the actual string that I am looking for, e.g. `"test"` then it functions as intended. My only thought is perhaps `$query['skill']` doesn't return as a string, but I can't do a `var_dump` to find out since I am using wordpress and I am changing code to effect ajax query.

```
global $user_ID;
$query = $_REQUEST['query'];

if (isset($_REQUEST['query']['skill'])) {
    if (isset($query['skill']) && $query['skill'] != '') {

global $wp_query, $ae_post_factory, $post, $current_user;
$post_object = $ae_post_factory->get(PROFILE);
$profile_id = get_user_meta( $user_ID, 'user_profile_id', true);
$profile = array('id' => 0, 'ID' => 0);
if($profile_id) {
    $profile_post = get_post( $profile_id );
    if($profile_post && !is_wp_error( $profile_post )){
        $profile = $post_object->convert($profile_post);
    }
}
$current_skills = get_the_terms( $profile, 'skill' );

if (!empty($current_skills)) {
    $c_skills = array();
    foreach ($current_skills as $key => $value) {
                $c_skills[] = $value->name;
            };

    if(in_array( $query['skill'], $c_skills )) {
        $query_args['tax_query'] = array(
                        'skill' => array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'skill',
                            'terms' => 'test',
                            'field' => 'slug'
                        )
                );
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a var_dump of `$c_skills` and `$query['skill']`?

Comment: $c_skills => ["test", "test2"] and $query['skill'] i am not sure about but $query = $_REQUEST['query']

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem come from `$query_args['tax_query']`.

For me, the Key (skill) has nothing to do here.

Try to make it simple with

```
$query_args['tax_query'] = array(
     array(
            'taxonomy' => 'skill',
            'terms' => 'test',
            'field' => 'slug'
      )
);
```

The place you use for skill between the two array is intended to be use for relation if you want to query more than one taxonomy.

Hope it works after this.

Comment: Hi @Benoti I think your misunderstood. I need to verify that the $query['skill'] which holds the query string supposedly from the form on wordpress i need to verify that it exists inside the specific array before i use it in tax_query. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Just reading your code once again, i don't know if it can be an issue : you have a semicolon right after the foreach closing accolade.